# Multiple inputs for .change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, parameters

I've got a table in which I want to remove a tablerow each time a checkbox is triggered in the row. I've got it working for one row (only if I specifically enter the row's ID). Is there some way to have a dynamic input for the javascript function? How do I do this?

HTML (embedded ruby)

```
<tr class="showContainer <%= "hideTableRow#{comment.id}" %>">
  <th><%= check_box_tag "approved#{comment.id}", comment.id, comment.approved, data: { toggle: "hideTableRow#{comment.id}" }, class: 'comment-approve' %></th>
    <th><%= comment.username %></th>
    <th><%= comment.email %></th>
    <th><%= comment.body %></th>
</tr>
```

This translates into (two entries).

```
<tr class="showContainer hideTableRow1">
  <th><input type="checkbox" name="approved1" id="approved1" value="1" data-toggle="hideTableRow1"></th>
    <th>foobar username1</th>
    <th>foobar email1</th>
    <th>foobar body1</th>
</tr>

<tr class="showContainer hideTableRow3">
  <th><input type="checkbox" name="approved3" id="approved3" value="3" data-toggle="hideTableRow3"></th>
    <th>foobar username3</th>
    <th>foobar email3</th>
    <th>foobar body3</th>
</tr>
```

My CSS:

```
.showContainer {
    display:block;
}
```

My JS:

```
$("#approved1").change(function () {
    $('.' + $(this).data('toggle')).toggle();
});
```

Obviously my JS now only applies to the first tablerow. How do I make it so that it affects both individually?

Excuse me if this is a total noob question. Learning JS is next-up, haha.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use `$("input")` or `$("input[type=checkbox]")` instead `$("#approved1")`. This solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select the containing row, correct? Try this:

```
$('.approved-checkbox').change(function(e){
    $(e.target).closest('.showContainer').toggle();
});
```

Then give the checkboxes the class of 'approved-checkbox' or whatever name you want to use.

[.closest() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)